# I recently started programming with HTML, so after I added my script to my code, I didn't know how to reload the page in order for the script to run

Tags: javascript, html

http://localhost:63342/untitled1exercise.1html/exercise1.html?_ijt=kk8leu22fhfgiu9fi47k34bc04

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
       </title>Hello world I'm Nour Belhassen and I am in the process of making a game<title/>
     </head>
     <body>

         </h1>Hello world I'm Nour Belhassen and I am in the process of making a game <h1/>
             <canvas id="asteroids" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
     <script>
         var canvars = document.getElementById("asteroids")
         var context = canvas.getContext("2d")
         context.strokeStyle = 'dimegrey';
         context.lineWidth = 5;
         context.rect(75,75,250,250);
         context.stroke();
         // this is a comment, it has no effect!!!
     </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Simply press F5.

Comment: For a future reference, localhost refers to your machine only. If you share links to localhost, people on other machines won't be able to visit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo.

```
// canvars
var canvars = document.getElementById("asteroids")

// canvas without 'r'
var context = canvas.getContext("2d")
```

this is why your script fails

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> on your keyboard to reload the page?

On Windows, you can also try <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>r</kbd>. On MacOS, it's <kbd>CMD</kbd><kbd>r</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

you can take a look at the [DOM content loaded event in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event).